# Trouble joining 3 different tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 7 and am trying to join 3 tables and for the most part, it is working great. The problem is that my table is returning the first test result it sees which is 33% and repeating it for all the other rows. I am new to joining in Laravel and need some assistance.
Here are my tables
**oex_students**
[image: oex_students table]
**oex_results** table
[image: oex_results table]
and finally the oex_exam_masters table
[image: oex_exam_masters table]
In the dashboard, I am calling the join in the index function within the AdminController.php

```
public function index()
    {
      $data['portal'] = Oex_portal::get()->toArray();

      $data['exams'] = Oex_exam_master::where('status', '1')->get()->toArray();
      $data['result_info'] = Oex_result::select('oex_results.*', 'oex_results.result as result')->get()->first();
      $data['students'] = Oex_students::select(['oex_students.*', 'oex_exam_masters.title as exam_name'])
      ->join('oex_results', 'oex_students.id', '=', 'oex_results.user_id')
      ->join('oex_exam_masters', 'oex_results.exam_id', '=', 'oex_exam_masters.id')
      ->get()
      ->toArray();


      $data['category'] = Oex_category::where('status', '1')->get()->toArray();
      $data['exams'] = Oex_exam_master::select(['oex_exam_masters.*', 'oex_categories.name as cat_name'])->join('oex_categories', 'oex_exam_masters.category', '=', 'oex_categories.id')->get()->toArray();
      return view('admin.dashboard', $data);
  }
```

In my dashboard where I am displaying the table is:

```
 @foreach($students as $key => $student)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ $student['name'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $student['email'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ $student['mobile_no'] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $student['exam_name'] }}</td>
           {{-- <td>{{ $student['result'] }}%</td> --}}
           <td>{{ $result_info->result }} %</td>
           {{-- <td>N/A</td> --}}


           @if($student['status']== 1)
           <td><input data-id="{{ $student['id'] }}" class="student_status" type="checkbox" name="status" checked></td>
           @else
           <td><input data-id="{{ $student['id'] }}" class="student_status" type="checkbox" name="status"></td>
           @endif

       </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Here is an image where the information is displayed:
[image: table view]
I want to call the result where the oex_students.id = oex_results.user_id but I am not sure how to go about this using Laravel. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Edit: When running dd(data['students']); this is what I get:
[image]
Edit 2:
After running the following in phpmyadmin:
`SELECT name, email, mobile_no, oex_exam_masters.title as exam_name, result, oex_exam_masters.status as status FROM oex_students LEFT JOIN oex_results ON oex_students.id = oex_results.user_id LEFT JOIN oex_exam_masters ON oex_exam_masters.id = oex_results.exam_id` 
I get what I want as seen below:
[image: image of correctly called table joins]

Comment: hi, can you put toSql() instead of toArray() and debug students with dd($data['students']) after it? that's gonna show us the final query getting done so we can discover in the SQL where to put a group by or something like that and then update accordingly

Comment: @MatteusBarbosa Thank you for your reply. toSql() method doesn't exist, so it says, anything else I can try? Thanks

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles  `toSql()` can't be called after `get()`. It must be called in lieu of `->get()`

Comment: ahhh ok. In that case, I get
```
"select `oex_students`.*, `oex_exam_masters`.`title` as `exam_name` from `oex_students` inner join `oex_results` on `oex_students`.`id` = `oex_results`.`user_id` inner join `oex_exam_masters` on `oex_results`.`exam_id` = `oex_exam_masters`.`id` ◀"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to change my query to the following to get it to work:

```
$data['students'] = Oex_students::select('name','email','mobile_no','oex_exam_masters.title as exam_name','result','oex_exam_masters.status as status')
        ->from('oex_students')
        ->join('oex_results', function($join) {
            $join->on('oex_students.id', '=', 'oex_results.user_id');
            })
        ->join('oex_exam_masters', function($join) {
            $join->on('oex_exam_masters.id', '=', 'oex_results.exam_id');
            })
        ->get();
```

All is well in the world. Thanks for the help which did get me closer to the answer.